# Call function use pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers

How can I use the value from `my_int_func` and `my_int_func2` as arguments to `sum` by using a function pointer?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void my_int_func(int x){
    cout<<x<<endl;
}


void my_int_func2(int y){
    cout<<y;
}
int main(){
    void (*huu)(int);
    huu = *my_int_func;
    (*huu)(2);
    void (*uuu)(int);
    uuu = *my_int_func2;
    (*uuu)(4);
    return 0;
}

void sum(int a, int b){

}
```

Comment: Its not clear what you want to do. Your two functions dont return a value, but they only print it on the screen. If you want to sum the two values that you send as parameters to those functions you simply have to call `sum(2,4)` which would be implemented as `void sum(int a,int b){return a+b;}`. There is no need for function pointers, and if you want to use them for exercise its not clear how you want to use them

Comment: the short answer is: you cannot, because the functions do not return anything and a function pointer alone also cannot tell you what parameters are passed to the functions.

Comment: What are you trying to do and why would you want to do it this way.  This is not cleaver coding, clever coding is doing the minimum possible to achieve the result, in this case cout << " 2 + 4 = " << (2+4); would  work.  Maybe you could look at templates, they might suit your needs better?

Comment: @tobi303 _"which would be implemented as ..."_ You missed to change the return type to `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: Your functions `void my_int_func(int x)` and `void my_int_func2(int y)` do not return anything (return type `void`). They just prompt the input parameters to `stdout`.

What you probably want is something like that

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int my_int_func(int x)
{
  return x;
}

int my_int_func2(int x)
{
  return x;
}

void sum(int x, int y)
{
  std::cout << x << " + " << y << " = " << (x + y) << endl;
}

int main()
{
  int (*f1)(int) = *my_int_func;
  int (*f2)(int) = *my_int_func2;
  sum(f1(1),f2(2));
}
```

This will hand the integer values 1 and 2 to `my_int_func`and `my_int_func2`. They will return those values as an input for `sum` which will then prompt `1 + 2 = 3`.

However the two functions aren't very useful. A better and less static way would be to read the numbers from the user input as Vlad pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean something like the following

```
#include <iostream>

int my_int_func()
{
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";

    int x = 0;
    std::cin >> x;

    return x;
}

int my_int_func2()
{
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";

    int x = 0;
    std::cin >> x;

    return x;
}

long long int sum( int(), int() );

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum( my_int_func, my_int_func2 ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

long long int sum( int f1(), int f2() )
{
    return f1() + f2();
}
```

Another possible approach is the following

```
#include <iostream>

int my_int_func()
{
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";

    int x = 0;
    std::cin >> x;

    return x;
}

int my_int_func2()
{
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";

    int x = 0;
    std::cin >> x;

    return x;
}

long long int sum( int, int );

int main()
{
    int ( *pf[2] )() = { my_int_func, my_int_func2 };

    int x = pf[0]();
    int y = pf[1]();

    std::cout << sum( x, y ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

long long int sum( int x, int y )
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Comment: Now the author of the question shall reveal to us what is the point of this syntactically cumbersome contraption.

Comment: @BR41N-FCK You can wait for the author a week.:) It is not so rare.:) If something  is wrong with my answer he always can write a comment to it and I will delete the answer.

Comment: @SothikVicheachann I appended my post and functions declared as parameters are implicitly converted to pointers. So these records int() and int ( * )() are equivalent.

Comment: thank Vlad for this but I am a new programmer so I am don't some point on you code : why you set x=0 at first and (int(), int()) mean ? sorry for this question because I am a new programmer.

Comment: @SothikVicheachann If an error occurs for example if a letter will be entered instead of a digit the value 0 will be returned from the function. It is like a default value. Otherwise you have to process errors for such a simple function.